# OS X Terminal Shell Script - How to compare value of 2 TXT files and run until False

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal

I have 2 files, 1 where NEW IP address is saved, 2 where previous IP is saved.
I want to loop my script until value returns false.

I have this:

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com > IPNEW.txt
echo Getting NEW IP..

until [ ! IPNEW.txt == IPOLD.txt ]
do 
    sleep 3
    echo IP found; dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
    dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com > IPNEW.txt
    echo Checking...
done
```

Why can't I use `"!"` ?
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your `[` test is comparing two manifestly different strings for inequality (the hard way — why not use `!=` instead of `! x == y`?).

You should probably use `cmp` to compare the contents of the files, or you should capture the results in variables and compare those.  I've not experimented with `dig`, but in principle, you should be able to use:

```
old=$(<IPOLD.txt)
new=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)

while [ "$new" = "$old" ]
do 
    sleep 3
    new=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)
    echo "IP found: $new"
    echo Checking...
done
```

Comment: You could also skip saving the new lookup in a variable, and just use it directly in the test: `while [ "$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)" = "$old" ]`

Comment: Only if you don't want to display it too.

Comment: @Jonathan You can display `$old`, in the while loop, it is equal to `$new`.